# How to add dynamic page URL in HTML template on Magento 2?

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento-2.1.3, html

Is there anyone expert to help me out how to add dynamic page URL in my mention file path?

For example:

I want to get Create account url in html file but I didn't set it. I was trying with `<?php echo geturl('create/account/create/'); ?>` and also `<a href="{{store direct_url="create/account/create"}}" /></a>`. But that code is not working. How can I set the url to html file in that path mentioned above.

File path:

```
app/design/......./Magento_Checkout/web/template/.html
```

Comment: Donot get ur point?Please explain briefly

Comment: I want to get Create account url in html file but I didn't set it. I was trying with <?php echo geturl('create/account/create/'); ?> and also <a href="{{store direct_url="create/account/create"}}" /></a>. But that code is not working. how can I set the url to html file in that path mention above.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, we can get the url by using: `mage/url`. Take a look:

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml**

[image]

As we can see, on the onepage checkout, Magento has set the the baseurl variable already. For example, we can get: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/error-processor.js` -
 `url.build('customer/account/login/')`

Additionally, each htm template on onepage will have a Js component. So, we need to find the Js component associated with the html template. We can override this Js file and add the more logic here.